# Tridion 2009 SP1 CMS failed to publish HTML pages

Tags: publishing

In Tridion 2009 SP1 CMS, publishing is failed for all the HTML pages with the below error while its successful for rest of the file formats. Also deployer log is not updated as well, as the file has not yet reached the publishing agent.

Please help.

> **Error**: JScriptException: Expression 'RenderComponentPresentation()' had error 'Could not find mediator for template type: text/xml'

Answer (score 4):

It looks like one of your component templates is using an XSLT TBB without having a mediator configured to handle it.
 You should either remove this/these TBBs  if you are not intending to use it or you can see various online articles on XSLT Mediator . one is here -

[Implementing the XSLT Mediator](http://yoavniran.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/implementing-the-xslt-mediator-part-1/)

Answer (score -2):

Same issue me also getting when I publish bulk pages getting below error message. If I publish one by one it's getting success.

JScriptException: Expression 'RenderComponentPresentation()' had error 'Could not find mediator for template type: text/xml'

Please help me

Comment: This is a question and answer site, so please do not put questions in an answer - move this to a new question, if the above information does not solve your problem